# c3js donut chart tooltips not showing

Tags: javascript, tooltip, c3.js, donut-chart

I am having a problem with C3js donut and tooltips. Tooltips are working perfectly in my lines charts, I don't understand what is not working in this case. 
Here is the codeine :   https://codepen.io/prtome/pen/LmKPpy

I am keeping it very simple - I am trying to see what is the best way to present a donut with many slices (thus taking out the labels inside the slides).
Here is the code 
HTML

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

JS

```
  var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: d3.select('#chart'),
  size: {
        width: 500
      },
  data:{
  columns: [
        ['data1', 30],
        ['data2', 120],
        ['data3',45],
        ['data120', 30],
        ['data121', 120],
        ['data311',56],
        ['data4', 30],
        ['data5', 120],
        ['data6',45],
         ['data7', 20],
        ['data8', 90],
        ['data9',45],
        ['data10', 30],
        ['data11',38],
        ['data12',33]
    ],
   type : 'donut'
  },
  donut:{
    label: {show:false  }
   },
   tooltip:{show:true},
   legend: {
    position:'right'
    }
  });
```

Any idea where I am wrong ? thank a lot

(using d3 4.13.0 and C3 0.6.1)

Answer (score 1):

As solution was given for a similar problem on the github of C3
add the following in the CSS

```
g.c3-chart {
  g.c3-event-rects {
    rect.c3-event-rect {
      pointer-events: none;
   }
 }
}
```

With that it works

Comment: This will break tooltip on bar chart.

Comment: I don't use bar charts so for me it is ok. It makes me think it its a bug in C3 and should be told on the github issues

Comment: There is a PR for it waiting to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with particular versions of C3js.
https://github.com/c3js/c3/pull/2359

It's now merged and solved. The best solution is simply using the most recent version, i.e. 0.6.7.